# Shooting day - when having a photo shoot - correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, photography

A lot of my friends work in the creative field and often they use " shooting day" when they have a photo shoot planned...
It's actually very irritating as I don't think that's correct... I mean you're not getting shot... hahaha

As I am not a native English person, I would like to ask if this is correct, why it's correct and if not, well, why not. :)

thank you very much!!

Comment: Why do **you** think it's not correct? Have you heard of a [photoshoot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/photo-shoot)?

Comment: If you have friends in the 'creative field', you might to have to get used to them using irritating phrases.

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" with the term.  It is ambiguous, but then just about every English sentence that one might utter is ambiguous, one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

Your friends are correct. It is a widely used industry term. It may sound strange to a non-native speaker, but that's the right term.

Consider these examples:

- [What to do if it's raining on the shooting day?](http://photo.net/portraits-and-fashion-photography-forum/00ZjUI)
- [Two Simple Tricks to Extend Your Shooting Day](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/content/two-simple-tricks-extend-your-shooting-day)

It is also used [in books on the subject](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22per%20shooting%20day%22):

> The unit is required to shoot 5 minutes of cut screen time per shooting day.
>
> Hollywood movies shoot one to three pages of the script per shooting day.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are not "a native English person".  You didn't mention the nationality of the other people.

Speaking as a native English person, I would have expected the term to be 'shoot day' rather than 'shooting day'.

However, that term is already used—it refers to game-shooting, e.g. 
[A Typical Shoot Day](http://mornacott-shoot.co.uk/pages/a-typical-shoot-day/85)

My guess is that the photographers use 'shooting day' in order to make the distinction between what they do and what game shooters do. It is only a guess though.

Comment: I suspect that in the US most would take "shooting day" to refer to firearms as well.  The unambiguous term would be "photo shoot day" or some such.

Comment: @HotLicks - thanks for that. I should have mentioned that I was speaking specifically about UK usage (or even narrower - usage by English people) as implied by the OP. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you place a *gerund* before a noun to make a compound noun, the gerund *usually* describes purposes.

A shooting day is a day for "shooting (a picture/photo)".

It is different from "a shooting star" where "shooting" describes the action of a star as a present participle.

A sleeping car: A railway wagon for sleeping. 
A sleeping baby: A baby who is sleeping.

A smoking room: A room for smoking. 
A smoking dish: A dish that is smoking.